# show href link only if one or more checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox

I've a set of checkboxes and also a main checkbox, If I check main chekbox then the rest will be checked but I can check one by one. So I've a Link and I want to show that link only if one or more checkboxes are checked, how?

EDIT:
This is the HTML code for test:

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" name="message_delivery" /></td>
            <td>Asunto</td>
            <td>Para</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="message_delivery[]" value="1" /></td>
            <td><a href="messages/show/id/1" class="read">sadasdasdas</a></td>
            <td>Demo Demo</td>
            <td>Wednesday, 05 de September de 2012 - 11:51:19 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="message_delivery[]" value="1" /></td>
            <td><a href="messages/show/id/1" class="read">sadasdasdas</a></td>
            <td>170ead917-FN 170ead917-LN</td>
            <td>Wednesday, 05 de September de 2012 - 11:51:19 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="message_delivery[]" value="1" /></td>
            <td><a href="messages/show/id/1" class="read">sadasdasdas</a></td>
            <td>Demo1 Lastname1</td>
            <td>Wednesday, 05 de September de 2012 - 11:51:19 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="message_delivery[]" value="1" /></td>
            <td><a href="messages/show/id/1" class="read">sadasdasdas</a></td>
            <td>174889ead-FN 174889ead-LN</td>
            <td>Wednesday, 05 de September de 2012 - 11:51:19 AM</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="button-bar">
    <a href="http://cmv.loc/messages/add">Escribir nuevo</a>
    <a id="btn_delete" class="btn_delete" style="display:none">Borrar marcados</a>
</div>
```

I want to show #btn_delete if one or more checkboxes are checked.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
    $('a').toggle($(':checkbox:checked').length > 0);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/RpxZd/1/

Comment: this toggles on every click.. doesn't reflect number of checked checkboxes

Comment: @zerkms exactly this is executed every time I click one checkbox and didn't work as I want

Comment: @ReynierPM: yeah, it was my fault

Comment: @zerkms ok it's working now and with some minors changes it was adapted to my code, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Bind onChange event to every checkbox and check if any of them is checked, show the link if it is. Event better... Instead of making loads of events just use delegation to do this.